# Node require() outside of Home directory in Windows

Tags: node.js

I am new to Node and am using it on Windows.

I found that after installing a package with npm, I can require it from the REPL if I start node in my home directory. When I navigate to another directory outside of home, `require()` does not find the package.

This is very confusing. I would have thought that installing something as a package makes it available anywhere, regardless of your path. How should I now require the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you execute `npm install <package>` following steps are produced:

- npm search for module and it's deps on npmjs
- downloading all packages to a temp folder
- running preinstall, install and postinstall script of them
- move package to a node_modules/ of current dir

So all project needed to install deps near it in node_modules/ dir.

Some packages can be installed globally, but it's done only for CLI tools liek grunt. To do that you need to execute `npm install -g <package name>`